# Company Retreat Forced PTO Usage

Tags: time-off, team-building

There's a multiple-night company retreat involving travel taking place that I have no interest in attending (for family reasons). It was stated that anyone who chooses not to attend must use PTO for the workdays missed if not attending the retreat, with the reasoning that the office will be closed for the retreat.

Myself and others however have been working from home consistently, so I see no reason why I couldn't work the handful of days from home and save my PTO. I'll have a chance to discuss this idea with my manager in the next couple of weeks; however, I'm not sure I should bother in the first place, as I have a feeling they won't be able to budge on the PTO usage. A part of me feels like I should just be thankful for the time off and take it...

Any advice on how to approach the situation would be appreciated.

Comment: Happens all the time with me. I'm not a Christian and all the forced vacations are for Christian stuff. I don't think employees can do much about it

Comment: @androidguy I don't think those are "forced vacations" those are "public holidays". They don't count against your vacation allowance.

Comment: @DJClayworth No. Where I work, we're required to take PTOs for 7-10 days during Christmas and the Christian new year. Only the Christmas day is a public holiday. That's why I'm left with hardly any PTOs for days that matter to me

Comment: I suppose public holidays are just government-enforced holidays. The only difference to employer-enforced holidays is that you aren't using your PTO.

Comment: I guess public holidays act as a right you have over your employer (they can't make you work) while forced PTO is a right your employer has over you (they can constrain how you spend your PTO).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're in the USA, most employers are legally allowed to require employees to take vacation time on specific days (forced vacation). Your state may have laws governing vacation time, so you should check what your state laws allow. That being said, if your state doesn't have specific laws regarding this then you're best bet is to take the PTO time as directed and not make an issue of it.

Comment: Even if they can't force you to take vacation, they can require you to attend the retreat. That leaves taking vacation voluntarily as your only option to avoid it.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't specify a country. You already got an answer for the USA, which traditionally is not great on worker protection compared to Europe. But even in Europe (Germany to be specific), companies have the right to shut down the office and order employees to take paid-time-off for those days.

While there are legal details to be considered (for example employees get mandatory days off and in return are required to take off full two weeks at a time at least once, so the employer could not simply tell the employee that they close the office in a way that would violate those conditions), shutting down the office for a few days for obvious reasons (no employees present) is not going to be any problem or run into any of the fringe edge cases.

In your case, *you* might be able to work, but there is literally nobody else. So if you have a question or need help or need a file or talk to someone, you will not be able to, because they are not available. So it would be easy to argue that you *could* work *maybe*, it would surely not be as effective as if it was normal operations.

So to summarize, shutting down the office, planned in advance, forcing the employees to take PTO is legal, even in places heavily guarded by labor laws like Germany.

My advice: take PTO, don't rock the boat and treat it like it is: a vacation. Maybe not your personal choice, but surely good enough to enjoy, instead of brooding over it.

Comment: My (UK government) office is closed on Christmas Eve, or the previous working day if that is a weekend, and I am required to use up one of my paid annual leave days. If, by some mischance I had no days left, I would have to either take unpaid leave (lose a day) or take 7 hours 24 mins of 'flexi leave' and claw that back over the next weeks or months.

Comment: I found a source, also on the laws in Germany: https://www.jobrecht.de/zwangsurlaub/. Issuing mandatory PTO is seen as an imposition on the employee and needs to be justified by pressing business reasons. If your work were entirely unaffected by the absence of your coworkers, you could appeal it on that basis.

Answer (score 4):

**Absolutely definitely take this up with your manager.**

Never assume that nothing can be done until you have asked.

Managers often have discretion on matters like this. And even if they formally don't, they can sometimes come to an arrangement where you formally take the PTO, actually work those days, and the manager will let you take 3 days off unofficially another time.

I would also consider whether there is something you can arrange to be able to attend the retreat. As someone who has organized retreats, it can sometimes be hard to get employees to actually go on them, to the point where so few employees attend that they are not worth it. Giving employees an "out" where they can work remotely instead of attending can make this problem worse. Whatever it is that is preventing you from attending, address that with your manager first. Maybe something can be done to remove that problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can of course go to the retreat. The company pays for it as work, you don’t lose any money, you don’t lose any holiday entitlement. This seems the better of your two alternatives.

Choice A: Sit at home for three days and three days holiday entitlement gone. Choice B: Go to the retreat, and have three days holiday at a time it suits you.

Comment: It is only the "better" of the alternatives if you totally disregard the OPs feelings on the matter

Comment: What have feelings got to do with this?

Comment: @gnasher729 - try asking the OPs partner that while they have to look after the kids :-S (or whatever the actual "family reasons" are).

Comment: Because as per the OPs question they do have an opinion about the retreat "I have no interest in attending (for family reasons)"

Comment: the op asked for advice

Comment: "I have no interest in attending" is a bit different from "It would be a problem to attend". I go on many work functions that I have no interest in.

Comment: I have no interest in attending because it would be a problem to attend, for family reasons. @mclayton hit the nail on the head.